# Where is GstElement properties description?

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I have recently started working with `gstreamer-1.0`, this is the first time I am working with a multimedia framework. I usually learn by looking at tutorials and already available implementations. The tutorial and documentation are good but I am not able to find descriptions on various properties of `GstElement`. `gst-inspect-1.0` provides one line description of the properties when looked up with element type.

```
signal-handoffs     : Send a signal before pushing the buffer
                      flags: readable, writable
                      Boolean. Default: true
silent              : silent
                      flags: readable, writable
                      Boolean. Default: true
single-segment      : Timestamp buffers and eat segments so as to appear as one segment
                      flags: readable, writable
                      Boolean. Default: false
```

*sample snapshot from `gst-inspect-1.0` while querying for `identity` element*

It would be really helpful if someone can guide me to some source of information regarding the aforementioned or something that I should read up on.

Comment: That's the thing, elements describe themselves. When in doubt check the source code what these options do.

Answer (score 0):

1. GstElement derives from gobject, and from which got the property feature. You can refer to [gobject property feature](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-properties.html) if you'd like
2. Then you can refer to [gstreamer property](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/args.html?gi-language=c) to see how to add a property for element.
3. The meaning of one specific property of one element depends. You can view the source code refer to the second step